# How to Add Arguments in Mozilla and IE drivers

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, firefox

While executing automation script I am getting enter captcha page in the browser.
to overcome that our development team provided a string which should be passed with URL to avoid this validation.

In Chrome, we have chrome options method to add arguments and its working fine for the driver.

Whereas If I am trying to execute my job on Mozilla & IE it's giving the same error.

Code Snippets:

```
else if(browser.equals("Chrome")){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", RunConfig.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE);
String userAgent = "******";
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
co.addArguments("--user-agent=" + userAgent); 
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY , co); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(cap); 
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
}
```

For chrome above code is working I need to see how we can run it for Mozilla and IE

Comment: Please don't scatter information everywhere, edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

Able to do it I am chaning the user agent which can be obtained in Mozilla and Chrome but in IE we cannot do that.

I am able to fix it in chrome with chrome options and in Mozilla with profile